# How to fit a curve to this data using scipy curve_fit

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, sigmoid

I am hoping someone can me with where I'm going wrong with fitting a curve to this data. I am using the method in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725139/fit-sigmoid-function-s-shape-curve-to-data-using-python) and so have the following code:

```
def sigmoid(x, L, x0, k, b):
    y = L / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))+b
    return y

p0 = [max(y1), np.median(x2), 1, min(y1)]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata=x2, ydata=y1, p0=p0, method='dogbox')

predictions = sigmoid(x2, *popt)
```

And my plotted "curve" looks like so:

[image: screenshot]

But I am expecting a more s-shaped curve. I have experimented with different p0 values but not getting the required output (and if I'm honest I'm not sure how I'm supposed to find the ideal starting parameters).

Using `p0 = [max(y1), np.median(x2), 0.4, 1]` and `method='trf` I did get the following, which is closer but still missing the curve in the middle?

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: That is because your y-axis is a log scale. If you change the y-axis to a linear one, you'll see that the fit is actually quite good.

Comment: Amazing - thank you. Have changed y-axis to linear and converted my y values to log(y) and it's spot on now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your y-axis is a log scale. If you change the y-axis to a linear one, you'll see that the fit is actually quite good.