# Modeling Sigmoid Curve with Time-Dependent Steepness in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, sigmoid

I have a dataset that follows a sigmoid curve, and I've observed that the sigmoid function becomes steeper over time. I'm looking for guidance on creating a model to fit this curve using Python. This question is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725139/fit-sigmoid-function-s-shape-curve-to-data-using-python) expect that the data curve becomes steeper over time. I've attempted to use a logistic regression to fit the data (as the other post suggests), but I need to incorporate a time-dependent parameter for the steepness.

The data is across a single day. In the images below, I've time segmented the data by hour. Meaning, each color represents data from a specific hour in the day. First, observe that for each color, the data follows a sigmoid curve (this is especially apparent for the orange data and is a property of the data I'm working with). Second, notice that the different colors follow different sigmoid steepnesses. For example, the blue curve follows a steeper sigmoid curve than the orange one does. From what I observed, the later in the day the data is from, the steeper the sigmoid curves become. I've attempted to show this property by drawing out the sigmoid curves in the second image.

[image]

[image]

Here was my attempt to fit this data:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Define a logistic function with a time-dependent parameter
def time_dependent_logistic(x, k, t):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-k * (x - t)))

# TODO: I replaced the variables below with my actual data 
X = ... # Example: np.random.rand(100) * 10  
time = ... # Example: np.linspace(0, 1, 100)  
y = time_dependent_logistic(X, k=5 * time, t=2) + 0.05 * np.random.randn(100)

# Fit the time-dependent logistic function to the data
popt, pcov = curve_fit(time_dependent_logistic, X, y, bounds=([0, 0], [np.inf, np.inf]))

# Generate predictions using the fitted parameters
X_test = np.linspace(min(X), max(X), 300)
y_pred = time_dependent_logistic(X_test, *popt)

# Plot the original data and the fitted logistic curve
plt.scatter(X, y, label='Original data')
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, label='Fitted time-dependent logistic curve', color='red', linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel('Input')
plt.ylabel('Output')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

However, the graph was not fitting the data properly. It simply produces a flat line:

[image]

I've researched ways into fitting the data properly so that the curve does not produce a flat line, but this is my first time attempting to model data like this, so I'm unsure if I'm even taking the right approach. Any guidance would be great. Thank you very in advance for your help. I've been very stuck on this problem for a long time, and I'm open to other methods of fitting the data as well.

EDIT:

I uploaded my data to Google Drive in case anyone wants to play around with it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aDB8U6Cn8lFo1TWFSRXWX-X0aEpCQ4sT/view?usp=sharing. Just a note, I shifted the X and Time columns to make the minimum 0, so it's not exactly the same data shown in the graphs.

Comment: Can you link to the actual data? Your curve should probably be of the form f(x/sigma(t)), where sigma(t) is the increasing spread parameter. If the problem is diffusive then sigma(t) would be proportional to a square root of t.

Comment: @lastchance Are you suggesting a similarity solution?

Comment: @jared, yes. Personally I'd have tried to fit a function y(x,t)=y0+A.tanh[c(x-x0)/t^p], with x0, y0, A, c and p parameters; p probably in the vicinity of 1/2, x0 about -50, y0 about 55, A about 40.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking a look, and apologies for delay. I've uploaded data here for you to access:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aDB8U6Cn8lFo1TWFSRXWX-X0aEpCQ4sT/view?usp=sharing

The time column is in seconds (relative to the start time). The x column is the input variable and the y column is the output.

Comment: @lastchance ^ please let me know if this is what you were looking for

Comment: @randomrabbit How do you tell the different sigmoid curves apart? Where does the color in the first graph come from?

Comment: I arbitrarily separated the data by hour to show the distinction in curves by time. For example, the orange dots might be all data points between hour 0 and hour 1, while the blue dots might be data points between hour 4 and hour 5. However, I imagine the shape of the sigmoid changes continuously as a function of time (rather than delineated exactly by hour).

Comment: I'm looking at this on a randomly generated dataset, and I see two potential problems. 1) The sigmoid cannot generate Y values larger than 1, so it can't fit a curve that ranges from 20-80. 2) There may be a scaling/initial guess problem. If X varies from 45350-45600, and k starts at k=1, then changing the k value will result in almost no change to the output curve, and curve_fit won't know to change that parameter.

Comment: In response to your first problem, the output is guaranteed to be between 0 and 100, so you can multiple the output of the sigmoid by 100 to scale it properly.

In response to your second problem, yes, that makes a lot of sense. I should look into that.

Comment: @randomrabbit, which 5 hours of data did you plot in your initial figure?

Comment: They are contiguous hours from 12 pm - 5 pm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I tried to fit a "switch" curve y=y0+A.tanh(c(x-x0)) to each hour of data (individually). The parameters x0, y0, A, c appear to depend on the hour, but it's difficult to say what hour of the day they correspond to because you've re-zeroed your time axis.

To get the optimize routine to work I had to supply decent initial guess (p0) and bounds based on the data for each hour.

[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Curve to be fitted (for ONE dataset)
def func( xval, x0, y0, A, c ):
    return y0 + A * np.tanh( c * ( xval - x0 ) )

# Read data from csv file
x, t, y = np.loadtxt( "data.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1, unpack=True )

hours_to_plot = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
colours = [ "black", "red", "orange", "yellow", "magenta", "blue" ]

xmin, xmax = 0.0, 200.0
fmthead = "{:4}" + 4 * " {:>11}"
fmtdata = "{:4}" + 4 * " {:>11.6}"

print( fmthead.format( "hour", "x0", "y0", "A", "c" ) )
for hour in range( 0, int( max( t ) / 3600 ) + 1 ):
    xhour = []
    yhour = []
    for i in range( len( t ) ):
        if hour <= t[i] / 3600.0 < hour + 1:          # 3600 seconds in an hour
            xhour.append( x[i] )
            yhour.append( y[i] )
    if len( xhour ) == 0: continue

    # Fit a switch curve to this hour's data
    x1, x2, y1, y2 = min( xhour ), max( xhour ), min( yhour ), max( yhour )
    p0 = [ 0.5*(x1+x2), 0.5*(y1+y2), 0.5*(y2-y1), 1.0 ]
    params, cv = curve_fit( func, xhour, yhour, p0=p0, bounds=( [ x1, y1, 0.0, 0.0 ], [ x2, y2, (y2-y1), np.inf ] ) )

    print( fmtdata.format( hour, *params ) )

    # Generate predictions using the fitted parameters
    xtest = np.linspace( xmin, xmax, 201 )
    ytest = func( xtest, *params )

    if hour in hours_to_plot:
        # Plot the original data and the fitted logistic curve for selected hours
        plt.scatter( xhour, yhour, s=4, color=colours[hour%6] )
        plt.plot( xtest, ytest, linewidth=2, label=f"hour {hour}", color=colours[hour%6] )
        plt.xlabel('Input')
        plt.ylabel('Output')
        plt.xlim( xmin, xmax )
        plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Parameters:

```
hour          x0          y0           A           c
   0     35.9892     32.7941      8.3595   0.0310962
   1     138.025      56.978     30.2371   0.0108192
   2     185.048     76.6886        14.0    0.013368
   3     102.521     47.7351     29.0443   0.0152189
   4     102.606     47.2297       13.29   0.0394483
   5     103.609     45.9815     26.7875   0.0283607
   6     109.932     56.2847     31.2823    0.044357
```

Comment: this is great. I think this solves the case where we separate time by hour. Apologies about zeroing the time data and for not centering the X input around 0. I think one way to improve upon this would be to figure out a general formula that doesn't segment by hourly time slots. But this is a great step in the right direction

Comment: Upon thinking about this more, I realized that my original solution did not even take time as a variable into the curve fit function